# Showing a fancybox with data after loading it from database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fancybox, infowindow

I'm facing some difficulties to show a fancybox from an `infoWindow` of a `marker` in the `Gmap`, there are many problems, for example I can't use `ng-click`, so I use `onClick`
When I load my function I get the data I need, but the `fancybox` is empty. Maybe because of the delay between execution of the query and displaying it.
So I have an empty array, after I execute the function of the `onClick` it gets filled correctly but not getting showed on the `fancybox`

**JS function**

```
getSelectedComments=function(info){
  $scope.selectedComments.length=0; // i nead to clear it before each time i execute the query
  $http.post('databaseFiles/selectedComment.php',{"com_id":info}).success(function(data){
  angular.forEach(data,
   function(selectedComment, key) {
     $scope.selectedComments.push(selectedComment);
   })
});

var $= jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href:'comments.html'
    });
});
}
```

**comments.html**

```
<h3 class="text-center">Les Avis</h3>
    <div class="iframe">
        <div id="class" ng-repeat="selectedComment in selectedComments">
        </div>
        <ul>
         <li  >{{ selectedComment.comment }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**selectedComment.php**

```
<?php
// Including database connections
require_once 'database_connections.php'; 
// mysqli query to fetch all data from database
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$query = "SELECT * from comments WHERE idClient=$data->com_id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$arr = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
// Return json array containing data from the database
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**HTML href that execute the function** (note that it's not on the main `html` it's in the content of a `Gmap marker` in the `JS`)

```
+'<a  onClick="getSelectedComments('+info.idClient+')" class="iframe">'+"Lire les avis"+'</a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that calling `$(".iframe").fancybox({})` would just make selected items clickable, but if you want something to open immediately, then you should simply use `$.fancybox.open()`? Check documentation - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#api

Comment: the fancybox opens with my code, if i try for exemple to show something already loaded it shows it corretyly, but if i want to show the data i mentioned before, it doesn't if you want i can add a pic